# Multiple parameter sets in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parameters, set, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Is it possible to use multiple sets to make two sets of parameters exclusive of each other, but inclusive with the other two sets? For example, say I had four parameters:

```
param(
    $param1,
    $param2,
    $param3,
    $param4,
)
```

Param1 and 2 are exclusive of each other, but can be called whether 3 or 4 are called. Similarly, param3 and 4 are exclusive of each other, but can be called whether 1 or 2 are called. These are the okay sets of parameters that can be called together:

```
./MyScript.ps1 -param1 -param3
./MyScript.ps1 -param1 -param4
./MyScript.ps1 -param2 -param3
./MyScript.ps1 -param2 -param4
```

These shouldn't be called at the same time:

```
./MyScript.ps1 -param1 -param2
./MyScript.ps1 -param1 -param3 -param4
./MyScript.ps1 -param2 -param3 -param4
./MyScript.ps1 -param3 -param1 -param2
./MyScript.ps1 -param4 -param1 -param2
./MyScript.ps1 -param3 -param4
```

I've tried a few things, but all of them seem to cause weird output, and still allow me to call what I would think to be "illegal" parameter sets. Here is an example of the parameter sets as I set them up:

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="onethree",Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="a or b")]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="onefour",Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="a or b")]
[ValidateSet("a","b")]
[string]$one,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="twothree",Mandatory=$true)]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="twofour",Mandatory=$true)]
[switch]$two,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="onethree")]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="twothree")]
[string[]]$PropertyClass,
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="onefour")]
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="twofour")]
[string[]]$PropertyName
```

The script executes, but it doesn't complete correctly (If I call it with $two, it tries doing something with $one and causes the script to fail). If I tab through the possible parameters, I don't see $two; but if I type `-t` and hit [tab], it will autocomplete to `-two`. Any ideas what could be causing this? Is it possible to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: It might help if you showed the command line that was actually failing. More generally have you considered that having only two parameters that have 2 possible values each might make more sense.

Comment: I think the autocompleting -two is a red herring. I tested the parameterset blocks using $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName and got the appropriate parametersets for each of the desired test cases and  "Parameter set cannot be resolved" errors for each of the undesired test cases. I believe the error is somewhere in the rest of the script and not in the defined parametersets.

Answer (score 3):

## Use `Get-Help`

The best way to see what the parameter sets are is to use `Get-Help My-Function`. I created a function called `Test-Sets` with your given `param()` block, and this is the output from `Get-Help`:

```
SYNTAX
    Test-Sets -one <string> {a | b} [-PropertyName <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-Sets -one <string> {a | b} [-PropertyClass <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-Sets -two [-PropertyName <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Test-Sets -two [-PropertyClass <string[]>]  [<CommonParameters>]
```

This looks like it satisfies your requirements, unless you always want 2 parameters, in which case I think the only thing you need to do is make `$PropertyClass` and `$PropertyName` mandatory in each of their 2 parameter sets.

If I'm missing something here, please clarify and include the failing command as @mike z requested.

Comment: One of the first two parameters are required, and both propertyname and propertyclass are optional. No matter which of the first two parametrs is called, only one of the last two parameters should be able to be called, and the other of the first two parameters shouldn't be able to be called; however, that is not the case. I can call `-one "test" -PropertyName "test" -two "test"`. It does limit me to only one of the -Property* parameters, but it doesn't limit the usage of `-one` or `-two` once I call one of the `-Property*` parameters.

Comment: I need to come up with a better failing example to show you without showing my actual code. I will post something when I come up with it.

Comment: You could also post the output of `Get-Help`. No actual code is displayed, so unless the parameter names themselves are secret it shouldn't be a problem..